# How to convert *any* cURL or node-fetch request into an Axios request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, curl, axios

I'd like to be able to copy any HTTP request from the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools and resend it from within node.js code as an **Axios** request. (Have tried node-fetch but found Axios better in several important ways). However, Chrome only has the following options for copying requests: *Copy as Powershell, Copy as fetch, Copy as node.js fetch, Copy as cURL (cmd), Copy as cURL (bash)*. It doesn't include an Axios option.

Have come across a couple of online tools that will convert cURL requests:

- https://curl.trillworks.com/  <== converts from cURL with options for *Ansible, Browser (fetch), Dart, Elixir, Go, JSON, Node.js (fetch), Node.js (request), MATLAB, PHP, Python, R, Rust or Strest*
- https://onlinedevtools.in/curl  <== converts from cURL with a subset of the options above: *Go, JSON, Node.js, PHP, Python, R, Rust or Strest*

But unfortunately neither of these have an option for Axios. I also haven't been able to find an npm package that would do the conversion. It needs to be repeatable so not sure what the best option would be but it can't just be a manual conversion - grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Why would chrome network tab be driving your development efforts? I would suggest you take a step back and explain why you are "copying CURL from network tab"  to begin with, and why that needs to be translated to an Axios request.. this makes no sense

Comment: @chrismillah The user needs to be able to copy a request from Chrome (complete with all HTTP headers etc.) and paste it into the UI - it is then added to the database and will be fired periodically via Axios for screenscraping.

Comment: @SteveChambers next time open a feature request https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/issues

Comment: Also, https://onlinedevtools.in/curl sends your curl command to their server, so you should remove any sensitive data from your curl command if you use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) and you can convert cURL to several languages.

1. Import a cURL command
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
2. Open Code panel for the request
   [image]
3. Here you can select any of the languages you want to convert.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

As you said:

> Need to find a way to do this, whether it be a npm package, Chrome
> extension, online tool or even **hand-crafted node.js code**.

I've made a code using [curlconverter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/curlconverter) (it is even one package behind one link that you used as example) that can help you.

It uses [toJsonString](https://github.com/NickCarneiro/curlconverter/blob/master/generators/json.js) method to first convert the cURL string to JSON and after that, a lot of "parses" to make a beautiful and useful Axios options array. The "parses" translate from the cURL:

- URL
- Method
- Headers
- Cookies
- Data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` and `application/json`).

If you need something else, you can use the code as a base and change it for your needs.

```js
const curlconverter = require('curlconverter');

function curlToAxios(curl){
  let parsedCurl = curlconverter.toJsonString(curl);
  parsedCurl = JSON.parse(parsedCurl)
  // For some reason, sometimes the URL returns with quotation marks at the beginning and the end
  const qm = ['%27', '\''];
  qm.forEach(element => {
    if (parsedCurl.raw_url.startsWith(element)) {
      // Removing last occurrence
      var pos = parsedCurl.raw_url.lastIndexOf(element);
      parsedCurl.raw_url = parsedCurl.raw_url.substring(0,pos) + parsedCurl.raw_url.substring(pos+element.length);
      // Removing first occurrence
      parsedCurl.raw_url = parsedCurl.raw_url.replace(element, '');
    }
  });
  let axiosObject;
  let axiosOptions = {
    url: parsedCurl.raw_url,
    method: parsedCurl.method,
  };
  if (parsedCurl.headers && Object.keys(parsedCurl.headers).length > 0) {
    axiosOptions.headers = parsedCurl.headers;
  }
  if (parsedCurl.cookies && Object.keys(parsedCurl.cookies).length > 0) {
    // Convert cookies to 'cookie1=a; cookie2=b;' format
    let cookies = '';
    Object.keys(parsedCurl.cookies).forEach(element => {
      cookies += encodeURI(element) + '=' + (parsedCurl.cookies[element] ? encodeURI(parsedCurl.cookies[element]) : '') + '; ';
    });
    if (!axiosOptions.headers) {
      axiosOptions.headers = {}
    }
    axiosOptions.headers.Cookie = cookies
  }
  if (parsedCurl.data && Object.keys(parsedCurl.data).length > 0) {
    let data;
    // Form data
    if(parsedCurl.headers && (parsedCurl.headers['Content-Type'].includes('application/x-www-form-urlencoded') || parsedCurl.headers['Content-Type'].includes('multipart/form-data')) ) {
      data = '';
      Object.keys(parsedCurl.data).forEach(element => {
        data += (data !== '' ? '&' : '') + encodeURI(element) + '=' + (parsedCurl.data[element] ? encodeURI(parsedCurl.data[element]) : '');
      });
    } else if(parsedCurl.headers && parsedCurl.headers['Content-Type'] === 'application/json') {
      // The data here is on first element key
      data = Object.keys(parsedCurl.data)[0]
      data = JSON.parse(data);
    }
    axiosOptions.data = data;
  }
  axiosObject = axios(axiosOptions);

  return axiosObject;
}
```

As it returns an Axios, you can use it normally:

```js
let curl = "curl --request POST \
--url http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/new \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{\"email\": \"email@example.com\",\"password\": \"123456\"}'"

let result = curlToAxios(curl)

result
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: Haven't had time to try this yet but it looks a great start on the face of it. Guess ideally it would be made into a [generator](https://github.com/NickCarneiro/curlconverter/tree/master/generators/javascript), tests added and submitted as a Pull Request... Guaranteed bounty points if you (or someone else?) could do this!

Comment: Hey, that's a good idea, I'm going to see more about the package and try to make the pull. I'll make an update when done

Comment: I'm a little busy to do it this week, if someone is available, feel free to do :)

Answer (score 1):

https://curlconverter.com/node-axios/ now supports converting curl to Axios.